# I can not make jQuery Table Sorter work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"/>
        <script src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myTable").tablesorter({sortList: [[0, 0]]});
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Repid Type Table</h1>
        <table class="tablesorter" id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <th>PERNR</th>
                <th>INNBOUND</th>
                <th>FIRSTNAME</th>
                <th>LASTNAME</th>
                <th>CATSHOURS</th>
                <th>DIFF</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>00017808</td>
                <td>26.50</td>
                <td>Roland</td>
                <td>Block</td>
                <td>1830.70</td>
                <td>1804.20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>123412</td>
                <td>111.34</td>
                <td>Koray</td>
                <td>Tugay</td>
                <td>945.56</td>
                <td>234.43</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the table I see does not seem to be functional at all. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're missing closed `</script>` tag for you "includes":

```
<script src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Update**

Fix source path. Might also consider to use some CDN to load your javascript library. For example https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.26.2/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js

Comment: Shouldn't rely on that website to act as CDN. Can get from numerous proper CDN's

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have changed it to:     <script src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> Still not working...